# Given piecewise-defined functions $f$ and $g$, for which $x$ is $f(x) > g(x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is a homework question from a precalculus class that I'm a TA for.

> Define the functions
>   $$
> f(x) = \begin{cases}
>   2x+12 &\text{if }\; x<0 \\
>   5 &\text{if }\; 0\leq x \leq 6 \\
>   x-7 &\text{if }\; x>6 \\
> \end{cases}
> \quad\text{and}\quad
> g(x) = \begin{cases}   
>   x+4 &\text{if }\; x<2 \\
>   8-x &\text{if }\; x\geq 2 \\
> \end{cases}\,.
> $$
>   Graph on a real number line all solutions to the inequality $f(x) > g(x).$

I wanted to write up a thorough solution to this exercise for my class, and figured I'd post it online to help anyone else who may wander across it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To compare $f$ and $g$, it is helpful to rewrite the two *piece*wise-defined functions above so that they each have the same number of *pieces*, and so that their pieces are each defined on matching subsets of their domains. One may feel inclined to say that we want to express the functions on *commensurate* domains. Anyways, we can write $f$ and $g$ as
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
  2x+12 &\text{if }\; x<0 \\
  5 &\text{if }\; 0\leq x <2 \\
  5 &\text{if }\; 2\leq x \leq 6 \\
  x-7 &\text{if }\; x>6 \\
\end{cases}
\quad\text{and}\quad
g(x) = \begin{cases}   
  x+4 &\text{if }\; x<0 \\
  x+4 &\text{if }\; 0\leq x<2 \\
  8-x &\text{if }\; 2 \leq x\leq 6 \\
  8-x &\text{if }\; x > 6 \\
\end{cases}\,.
$$
Now we can find where $f(x) > g(x)$ by considering the pieces individually. We'll consider the top *piece* of each function first. On the subset of the domain where $x<0$, $f(x) = 2x+12$ and $g(x) = x+4$. So, restricted to this subset of the domain, $f(x) > g(x)$ if 
$$
\begin{align}
2x+12 &> x+4 \\
\iff \quad x &> -8\,.
\end{align}
$$
But we are only considering the subset of the domain where $x<0$, so in general, $f(x) > g(x)$ for $x$ such that $x<0$ *and* $x>-8$, which is all $x$ in the interval $(-\infty, 0) \cap (-8, \infty) = (-8,0)$. We can similarly consider the other three pieces. We have $f(x) > g(x)$ where
$$
\begin{align}
5>x+4 \;&\text{ and }\; 0 \leq x < 2\,, \\
5>8-x \;&\text{ and }\; 2 \leq x \leq 6\,, \\
\text{or where}\;\;x-7>8-x \;&\text{ and }\; x>6\,.
\end{align}
$$
These three intervals where $f(x) > g(x)$ are $[0,1)$, $(3,6]$, and $\left(\frac{15}{2},\infty\right)$ respectively, so $f(x) > g(x)$ for all $x$ in the set 
$$
\begin{align}
(-8,0) \cup [0,1) &\cup (3,6] \cup \left(\frac{15}{2},\infty\right)
\\[1em]
=\;\; (-8,1) &\cup (3,6] \cup \left(\frac{15}{2},\infty\right)\,.
\end{align}
$$
Graphed on the real line, this set looks like:

[image: solution graphed on a number line]

Then if we wanted to be a bit extra about it, we could graph the functions $f$ and $g$ to visually verify that our solution is correct. In the graph below, $\color{red}{f \text{ is red }}$ and $\color{blue}{g \text{ is blue }}$.

[image: the graphs of the functions f and g]